# how to get values to update in c++

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int slotWild = 0;
   int slotOne = 1 + slotWild;
   int slotTwo = 1 + slotOne;

   cout << slotWild << slotOne << slotTwo;
   slotWild -= 1;
   cout << slotWild << slotOne << slotTwo;
   slotWild -= 1;
   cout << slotWild << slotOne << slotTwo;
   return 0;
}
```

the output that I get it is:

0 1 2

-1 1 2

-2 1 2

so my question is, why don't the other values update if the value of slotWild is included in slotOne and slotTwo's definition? For example, you would expect the output for the 2nd and 3rd line to be:

-1 0 1

-2 -1 0

Comment: Because that's how C++ works. If a variable was used to compute another variable, and then the original variable's value changes, that has no effect, whatsoever, on the 2nd variable. C++ is not like a spreadsheet, where changing one cell automatically updates some other cell whose formula references the first cell. That's not how C++ works.

Comment: When you write `int slotOne = 1 + slotWild;`, the expression `1 + slotWild` is evaluated, and the value is stored in a memory location associated with `slotOne`. After this operation happens, `slotOne` retains no memory of "how" it got to where it is now. An `int` in c++ simply holds a numeric value between (likely) (-2^31) and (2^31)-1.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't "definitions", they're assignments. When you say `x = y + 1` you're saying "assign to `x` the value of `y`, as of right now plus 1".

If you want it to be dynamic you must define a function, as in:

```
int slotOne() {
  return 1 + slotWild;
}
```

Where that requires `slotWild` to be a class property or a global variable.

That means you'll need to call it as well, as in:

```
cout << slotWild << slotOne() << slotTwo();
```

A function is evaluated *each time it is called* whereas a variable is initialized only once and after that point the value won't change unless the variable has been modified.

As Walnut points out, that C++ statement is actually two parts:

```
int slotOne = 1 + slotWild;
^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |              \- Variable Initialization
    \--- Variable Definition
```

The initialization part happens the instant this variable is defined, as in when that line of code executes.

(As with many things in C++ that's not always the case, but as a general rule that's how it works.)

Comment: They are *definitions* and it is initialization, not assignment. Unfortunately the word "*definition*" has a different meaning in C++ than it does in mathematics.

Comment: @walnut Yeah, trying to walk the line here between mathematical definitions and C++ definitions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something like that. Appreciate it :)

Comment: @dv1651st In case you aren't aware: Have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). The comment section is not meant for "*thank you*" comments and similar ones. Instead you can upvote answers if they helped you (once you have enough reputation) and you can *accept* the answer that was most helpful to you by clicking the check mark next to it. (You don't *have* to do anything, though.)